# slideshow works locally but not on live site

Tags: javascript, slideshow

I created this FlipBoard style slideshow and it works fine locally. I'm using pure javascript because the site I'm uploading it to claims to not work well with jQuery. However, it doesn't work on the live site. I created a jsFiddle to see if it would work there, still not working even though it claims the code is valid.

Here is the basic html structure:

```
    <ul id="featured">
    <li id="first" class="box">
        <ul class="captions">
            <li><a href="#"><span>Red</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span>Green</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span>Blue</span></a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="images">
            <li style="background:#ff0000"><a href="#"></a></li>
            <li style="background:#00ff00"><a href="#"></a></li>
            <li style="background:#0000ff"><a href="#"></a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="second" class="box">
        <ul class="captions">
            <li><a href="#"><span>Red</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span>Green</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span>Blue</span></a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="images">
            <li style="background:#ff0000"><a href="#"></a></li>
            <li style="background:#00ff00"><a href="#"></a></li>
            <li style="background:#0000ff"><a href="#"></a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="third" class="box">
        <ul class="captions">
            <li><a href="#"><span>Red</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span>Green</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span>Blue</span></a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="images">
            <li style="background:#ff0000"><a href="#"></a></li>
            <li style="background:#00ff00"><a href="#"></a></li>
            <li style="background:#0000ff"><a href="#"></a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
```

Here is the javascript:

```
window.onload = function(){

function animate(elem,style,unit,from,to,time) {
    if( !elem) return;
    var start = new Date().getTime(),
        timer = setInterval(function() {
            var step = Math.min(1,(new Date().getTime()-start)/time);
            elem.style[style] = (from+step*(to-from))+unit;
            if( step == 1) clearInterval(timer);
        },25);
    elem.style[style] = from+unit;
}

function Flip(X) {

    // DECLARE IMAGES
    var thisImg = X.children[1];
    var lastImg = thisImg.children[thisImg.children.length-1];
    var firstImg = thisImg.children[0];
    var secondImg = thisImg.children[1];
    console.log(X, thisImg);
    console.log(firstImg, secondImg, lastImg);

    // DECLARE CAPTIONS
    var thisCap = X.children[0];
    var lastCap = thisCap.children[thisCap.children.length-1];
    var firstCap = thisCap.children[0];
    var secondCap = thisCap.children[1];

    animate(secondImg,"height","px",298,0,750);
    animate(firstImg,"height","px",0,298,750);
    animate(secondCap,"opacity","",1.0,0.0,750);
    animate(firstCap,"opacity","",0.0,1.0,750);

    thisImg.insertBefore(lastImg,firstImg);
    thisCap.insertBefore(lastCap,firstCap);

}

[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.box'), function(item) {
    setInterval(function(){Flip(item);}, Math.floor(Math.random()*24000) + parseFloat(12000));
});
```

};

Here is the jsFiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/FWucA/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are not able to capture the onload function on live site. I have updated your JS fiddle code to not use window.onload and it works fine.
[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FWucA/2/)

```
function onloading() {

function animate(elem, style, unit, from, to, time) {
    if (!elem) return;
    var start = new Date().getTime(),
        timer = setInterval(function () {
            var step = Math.min(1, (new Date().getTime() - start) / time);
            elem.style[style] = (from + step * (to - from)) + unit;
            if (step == 1) clearInterval(timer);
        }, 25);
    elem.style[style] = from + unit;
}

function Flip(X) {

    // DECLARE IMAGES
    var thisImg = X.children[1];
    var firstImg = thisImg.children[0];
    var secondImg = firstImg.children[1];
    var lastImg = thisImg.children[thisImg.children.length - 1];

    // DECLARE CAPTIONS
    var thisCap = X.children[0];
    var firstCap = thisCap.children[0];
    var secondCap = firstCap.children[1];
    var lastCap = thisCap.children[thisCap.children.length - 1];

    animate(secondImg, "height", "px", 298, 0, 750);
    animate(firstImg, "height", "px", 0, 298, 750);
    animate(secondCap, "opacity", "", 1.0, 0.0, 750);
    animate(firstCap, "opacity", "", 0.0, 1.0, 750);

    thisImg.insertBefore(lastImg, firstImg);
    thisCap.insertBefore(lastCap, firstCap);
}
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.box'), function (i) {
    setInterval(function () {
        Flip(i);
    }, 1000);
});
};

onloading();
```

Comment: beat me up by seconds :) i just made the same.

Comment: @pasty Even I checked right before posting to see it is already been answered :)

Comment: @lucidego you can also change JSFiddle example to run on onDomready instead of onLoad (change the dropdown in top left). That works fine too.

Comment: I tried you solution but it didn't work, because to <ul> is generated dynamically. I applied a setTimout for 5 seconds and it works. Is the another way to delay the function until after the page is loaded. Also, the second <li> is not collapsing while the first expands.

Comment: @lucidego Did you try the JS Fiddle link that I have mentioned, bcoz its working just fine.